# Link mulitple mutations in AppSync

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-appsync

I'm doing an application in AppSync and I'm trying to create with Cloud Formation one schema where one mutation is linked to one resolver and a second mutation is linked to a second resolver. But it always give me an error saying that I can't attach two mutations in a single request.

If I try to do in console, I can attach two mutations in two resolvers.

Someone has any idea how I can provision everything in Cloud Formation ?

[EDIT] I added this resolver to the template

```yaml
AppSyncMutationResolverOne:
   Type: "AWS::AppSync::Resolver"
   DependsOn: AppSyncSchema
   Properties:
     ApiId: !Ref GraphApiId
     TypeName: Mutation
     FieldName: exampleOne
     DataSourceName: !GetAtt DataSourceOne.example
     RequestMappingTemplate: !Ref RequestMappingTemplate
     ResponseMappingTemplate: !Ref ResponseRequestMappingTemplate
```

But when I try to add a second Mutation Resolver, pretty similar with this first one

```yaml
 AppSyncMutationResolverTwo:
    Type: "AWS::AppSync::Resolver"
    DependsOn: AppSyncSchema
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref GraphApiId
      TypeName: Mutation
      FieldName: exampleTwo
      DataSourceName: !GetAtt DataSourceTwo.example
      RequestMappingTemplate: !Ref RequestMappingTemplate
      ResponseMappingTemplate: !Ref ResponseRequestMappingTemplate
```

It returns me an error saying that I can't add two mutation resolvers to the same API

This is my RequestMappingTemplate that is used for both mutations:

```yaml
    {
       "version": "2017-02-28",
       "operation": "Invoke",
       "payload": { 
             "arguments": $utils.toJson($context.arguments)
          }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code you're trying to deploy?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with the cloud formation sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cloudformation template seems fine to me, but, depending on which type of `DataSource` you are using, you define the name of the field on the `RequestMappingTemplate` too (i.e. Lambda data source) as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-overview.html), like this:

```json
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "operation": "Invoke",
    "payload": {
        "field": "getPost",
        "postId": "1",
    }
}
```

So, based on that, it seems that you're using the same `RequestMappingTemplate` for the two mutation resolvers. Check that the two Request Mappings correspond to the same `FieldName` defined on the Cloudformation template for each resolver. That could be the reason why it works on the console but not through Cloudformation.

Comment: Hi, I added the request mapping template I'm using for both mutations. In this case, I only pass arguments... Should I pass field too ?

Comment: Yes, you should pass it too! in that case you would need two different request mapping templates, one for each resolver.